# classifier : axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, sklearn-pandas

I'm using ScikitlearnRandomForestClassifier as below.

```
from art.estimators.classification.scikitlearn import ScikitlearnRandomForestClassifier as SRFC
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier as RFC

model_rand_forest = SRFC(RFC(n_estimators=500,
                             max_depth=45,
                             criterion='entropy',
                             random_state=32))
model_rand_forest = model_rand_forest.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

I ran into the following error. If needed, `y_train` is a series of the size `(70540,)` and `x_train` is of the size `(70540, 128)`.

```
error:
 File "<ipython-input-18-c410427d7973>", line 1, in <module>
    model_rand_forest = model_rand_forest.fit(x_train , y_train)

  File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\art\estimators\classification\classifier.py", line 71, in replacement_function
    return fdict[func_name](self, *args, **kwargs)

  File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\art\estimators\classification\scikitlearn.py", line 138, in fit
    y_preprocessed = np.argmax(y_preprocessed, axis=1)

  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in argmax

  File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 1186, in argmax
    return _wrapfunc(a, 'argmax', axis=axis, out=out)

  File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 61, in _wrapfunc
    return bound(*args, **kwds)

AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1
```

Answer (score 0):

you will have to provide the labels y one-hot encoded with shape (nb_samples, nb_classes) to the ART estimators for scikit-learn models.
you can use this link to put your labels in one-hot format.
https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-one-hot-encode-sequence-data-in-python/